# May any former felons legally purchase modern firearms after expungement?

Tags: us-federal-government, firearms, michigan, expungement

The state in question is Michigan, but I'm curious about the question in America generally. I'm aware about Michigan's [requirements](https://www.willis.law/criminal-defense/expungements/new-expungement-laws/) before petitioning for expungement.

I'm not clear if either or both any fenly or all felonies are claimed *by federal law* to restrict once convicted persons from legal access to *modern* firearms for life. I know about the black powder rifle/antique exception.

If the person in question successfully petitions the governor, can gun rights be 'fully' restored? Are convicted persons always required to petition the BATF or only for certain felonies or only in certain states?